# How to remove the lock screen that appears after the emulator boots up to main screen in Android 2.1

Tags: android

The lock screen appears at the main screen, after the emulator boots up. I want to disable locking at main screen, so that the next time I boot up my emulator the lock screen will not appear. Can anybody suggest the best solution for this?

Comment: Take a look to my answer to [this post][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically/10535284#10535284

Comment: take a look to my answer to this post...It worked fine for me! [post answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically/10535284#10535284)

Answer (score 12):

The latest version of the Android OS 4.2.2 has a way to remove it via the emulator Settings. Just go to : Security >> Screen Lock, and select "NONE." Make sure you are saving the emulator settings to Snapshot so you don't have to keep going through these same steps.

Comment: If you use a snapshot, doing settings is redundant as you can save a snapshot after unlocking.

Answer (score 7):

I just suffered this issue as well (not sure if it could be solved programatically) and found that hitting page up worked for me.

http://forum.archosfans.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=30574

Comment: thanks that worked for me.
on MAC I pressed F2 and emulator lock disappeared. . .

Answer (score 2):

The lock screen is started by a service.The service is WindowManagerService.In the service ,the code "wm.systemReady()" starts the Lock sceen.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't unless you create your own home screen.

Comment: I have created my own Home screen. While checking the Home screen on Linux emulator, Emulator boot to my Home screen directly without showing any LOCK. But when i am using the ramdisk.img,system.img, userdata.img file for the Windows emulator. Lock apears for my Home screen. Please suggest How to remove lock in this case???

Comment: I haven't found any setting in the device to turn-off the lock!

Comment: I don't want change the LOCK through the device setting.. I want to do it programatically so that next time when i boot my emulator or device no LOCK screen apears.

Answer (score 1):

From this [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robotium-developers/jpG8FEAMRLM/8pc-VsR9j8EJ):

1. If you are the developer or have access to the code of the
   application under test then the best and the easiest way of achieving
   this is using:
   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/activity_testing.html

   ```
    KeyguardLock keyguardLock = ((KeyguardManager)keyguardService).newKeyguardLock(TAG);

    if (enable) {
       keyguardLock.reenableKeyguard();
    } else {
       keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
    }
       return true;
    }
   ```

   In my opinion this is a nasty solution as it requires you to include an
   extra permission in your application -- one that virtually no
   application will need.

   As [OP] mentioned, you should remove this, but people forget: I've seen a
   few apps released on the Market that still have this permission
   included, when it really should have been removed.

   If you can *automatically* only include this permission for test builds,
   or automatically remove the permission when doing a release build, then
   fine.
2. Second best method is to use adb shell commands to unlock it at
   boot of the emulator. The actual code would differ depending upon what
   method you use to call these commands. This of course has the
   limitation that it can be run only at the first start up of the
   emulator, once the emulator has started this command would do nothing.

   You can run the "adb shell" command as often as you like.  On the first
   startup, it will open the Android menu, which should be harmless.  On
   each subsequent startup, it will press Menu, which will unlock the
   screen, as desired.
3. Third method is telnet into the emulator and then use the EV_KEY to
   unlock it.

   telnet localhost 5554
   event send EV_KEY:KEY_MENU:1 EV_KEY:KEY_MENU:0
   quit

   You can put this in a bat or shell file and call it from your test to
   unlock the Home screen. This again has the limitation of being able to
   unlock at only the first boot and cannot be used to unlock the Home
   screen after the first boot.

   This seems backwards.  The home screen is not locked when you start an
   emulator for the first time.

   In any case, I wouldn't recommend this at all, since we have the more
   reliable "adb shell" solution above.  Which also should work on real
   devices.
4. Fourth option is to use maven to unlock it.
   http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-7185
   This is very useful for CI purposes but is limited by inability to
   unlock the screen from eclipse. So if you are writing your tests in
   Eclipse you have to run the tests using command prompt if you need to
   unlock the screen.

   Clarification: that bug report is about the Android Emulator plugin for
   Jenkins/Hudson, and not Maven.  The Maven solution mentioned there just
   uses the "telnet" option above.
5. Finally, a further option is to use Android emulator snapshots.
   Introduced in Android SDK Tools v9, the emulator now supports saving the
   current state of the emulator (similar to other virtualisation products
   like VMware).

   So you could start the emulator once, so that it becomes unlocked, then
   shut it down.  Starting the emulator subsequently will immediately load
   up a clean emulator with the screen unlocked (so long as you do not save
   emulator state at shutdown (i.e. the "--no-snapshot-save" option).

   BTW, this snapshot functionality will be automated and included in the
   next release of the Android Emulator Plugin for Jenkins/Hudson.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps worked for me.

Steps: Go to AVD Manager -> Right click on the Virtual Device -> Wipe Data

Answer (score -1):

[image]

1. Andy (Right Click) - Settings - VMI Import Tool
2. Andy (Right Click) - Andy VM Launcher - Delete This Andy - New Andy - Launch