# Lock the Android device programmatically

Tags: android, android-emulator, locking, device-admin

I have been trying to lock the device through program. But I can't find the solution still.
I want to lock Android froyo2.2 through program. I have tried keyguardmanager and DeviceAdminManager.

My app is to remote lock the device. When message is received with some code words to lock then it locks the phone. I have found many Api_demo program as solution but I can't extract lock code alone from that and find solution.

Comment: then supply the answer yourself, and accept it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The activity class should be inner class and the outter class should extend DeviceAdminReceiver

```
public class adminActivity extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

   public static class Controller extends Activity {

                    DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
            ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
                mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(Controller.this,
                        adminActivity.class);
      }
   }
}
```

To lock the device write the code in the event where you use to lock

```
if (active) {
mDPM.lockNow();
}
```

If DeviceAdmin is enabled then  the phone will be locked.
To enable the device admin, the DevicePolicyManager intent is  called and it should be enabled by the user.

```
Intent intent = new   Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);  
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
```

Comment: adithi waht is securemeAdmin and active ?i have same problem. can u explain

Comment: can anyone please say what is active and what is secureadmin here?

Comment: This above code is taken from DeviceAdminSample present in Android sdk samples that are available with Android SDK. APIDemos-->app

Comment: Would have seriously helped save a lot of time had you just pasted what securemeAdmin was.

Comment: The complete code can be seen in the accepted answer of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987847/devicepolicymanager-locknow-is-not-working-for-motorola-tablets

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve this task you can take a look to [NoKeyGuard source code](http://code.google.com/p/futonic-lockscreenswitchwidget/source/checkout) and more precisely to a NoKeyGuard Service class and KeyguardLockWrapper class.

To unlock the device write the code in the event where you use to unlock:

```
    Context context= getApplicationContext();
    KeyguardManager _guard = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock _keyguardLock = _guard.newKeyguardLock("KeyguardLockWrapper");
    //to disable
    _keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
    //to enable
    _keyguardLock.reenableKeyguard();
```

Comment: This is now obsolete.  Do not use!

Answer (score 1):

The activity class should be the inner class and the outer class should extend `DeviceAdminReceiver`

```
public class adminActivity extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    public static class Controller extends Activity {

                DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
        ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(Controller.this,
                    adminActivity.class);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.screenBrightness = 0;
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Comment: This used to work, say in Android 2.3, but does not work any more.