# Not able to lock android phone programmatically

Tags: android, keyguardlock

I have been trying to lock my phone programmatically when some particular condition is met. In my case a for loop which loops for 10 times.

Here's what I am doing to lock my phone

```
private DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager; 
private ComponentName mComponentName;
```

In my onCreate:

```
mDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mComponentName = new ComponentName(this, AppAdminReceiver.class);

KeyguardManager keyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock = keyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

In one of my func when the for loop loops for 10 times this get executed

```
lock.reenableKeyguard();
mDevicePolicyManager.lockNow();
```

But it does'nt seem to work. Can some one help me? And also the KeyGuardLock class has been deprecated I guess. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Did you use the USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987847/devicepolicymanager-locknow-is-not-working-for-motorola-tablets

Comment: @ZohraKhan Thanks ur reply :) I got it working using this: Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
          intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mComponentName);
          intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,description);
          startActivityForResult(intent, ADMIN_INTENT);
          mDevicePolicyManager.lockNow();