# How to use FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD with fingerprint sensor

Tags: android

Applying the FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD on an activity till date would unlock the unsecure keyguard. And in case of secure keyguard it would present pin code prompt.

On devices with fingerprint sensor like Nexus 6P or 5X (Marshmallow 6.0), the flag causes pin lock prompt to be shown, while prompt is shown, fingerprint sensor vibrates but doesn't work to unlock.

So is there an official way to go about using the flag on Fingerprint sensor devices?

EDIT : I'm not exactly sure if pin lock prompt is shown, I can't test specifically as I don't have a device. But I'm sure the flag is not incorporating the fingerprint sensor logic

Comment: Do you mean devices such as the Nexus 6P and 5X which use Marshmallow's fingerprint API? Or other manufacturers' devices which run prior versions of Android and have their own custom fingerprint API?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm referring to Nexus device and official API only. But AFAIK, there's no API to request an unlock via sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem has to do with this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79735).

It has high priority since December '15, but no fix so far..

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This is totally frustrating and very irresponsible on Google's part. I see Greenify has included a "slower workaround". Can someone find out what's the workaround, except using root.

Comment: Looks like Google has marked it Working as Intended without any proper explanation.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79735#c110 and also here
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191955#c23

They also say that "developers are using it incorrectly". I mean seriously? What is going on here!!!