# How to lock android device by using programatically...Is it Possible?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lock the android device programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically)

Can any one help me how to lock a device using java Program, and here i am not using any UI means i am doing on the Service and user can not know what happening in his device.
by using msm Notification i am going to locking the device without user permission.
I Tried KeygardManager and DeviceAdmin but they are giving Security exceptions.

Is there any one to help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yet again, you want to lock someone elses phone without them knowing about it. A very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

yes, It is possible, try this code,

```
KeyguardManager mgr = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = mgr.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

for better understand , please visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically).

Comment: thanks man, but i did in some other way.

Comment: @Jinka, if you did, it would be really useful if you share your solution with others -- it is the entire point of SO.

Comment: Do not use this!  It is now obsolete.