# Lock phone using a android application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lock the android device programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically)

I was trying to lock phone using a application,

I have tried the following code, but no use,I inserted user permissions too.

```
KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = manager.newKeyguardLock("hh");
lock.disableKeyguard();
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

Please suggest me a code to lock the phone.

Comment: Please refer to following link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

and

```
KeyguardManager mgr = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = mgr.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```