# Lock Android phone (which has a security enabled lock like a pattern lock) programatically

Tags: android

I have read very many articles on locking an Android screen programatically, but am confused as to which method to use when the phone has a security enabled lock such as a pattern lock, as opposed to just a simple swipe lock.
Could anybody advise me on the best method and possibly an explanation/tutorial/article.
Thanks very much
P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock the android device programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically)

Comment: thanks for the help