# How to simulate a click on the power button in Android with C# Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I want to write a small application so that when it starts, it starts counting for 100 seconds and then simulates a click on the power button. To send the device to sleep. How to simulate a click on the power button in Android with C# Xamarin? Thanks for advance

Comment: you might wanna take look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock the Android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to lock screen, use the device manager DevicePolicyManager to lock screen and use PowerManager to display the screen.

1. inherit DeviceAdminReceiver

   ```
   public class ScreenOffAdminReceiver: DeviceAdminReceiver
   {
   private void showToast(Context context,string msg)
   {
       Toast.MakeText(context, msg, ToastLength.Short).Show();

   }
   public override void OnEnabled(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
       base.OnEnabled(context, intent);
       showToast(context, "Device Manager enable");

   }

   public override void OnDisabled(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
       base.OnDisabled(context, intent);
       showToast(context, "Device Manager is not enabled");

   }
   ```

   }
2. PowerManager and DevicePolicyManager

   ```
   private DevicePolicyManager policyManager;
   private ComponentName adminReceiver;
   private PowerManager mPowerManager;
   private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;


   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);



       adminReceiver= new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ScreenOffAdminReceiver)).Name);
       policyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)GetSystemService(Context.DevicePolicyService);

       mPowerManager = (PowerManager)GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
   }
   ```
3. Check screen state

   ```
     private void BtncheckAndTurnOnDeviceManager_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
       Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ActionAddDeviceAdmin);
       intent.PutExtra(DevicePolicyManager.ExtraDeviceAdmin, adminReceiver);
       intent.PutExtra(DevicePolicyManager.ExtraAddExplanation, "After you turn it on, you can use the lock screen function....");
       StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);

   }

   private void Btncheckscreenoff_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       bool admin = policyManager.IsAdminActive(adminReceiver);
       if (admin)
       {
           policyManager.LockNow();
       }
       else
       {
           showToast("No device management permissions");
       }

   }

   private void Btncheckscreenon_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       mWakeLock = mPowerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "tag");
       mWakeLock.Acquire();
       mWakeLock.Release();

   }

   private void Btncheckscreen_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
       bool screenOn = pm.IsScreenOn;
       if (!screenOn)
       {
           showToast("The screen is a black screen");
       }
       else
       {
           showToast("The screen is bright");

       }

   }
   ```

Please confirm permission in mainifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```